# Carousel slide messing up constantly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head      content must come *after* these tags -->
<title>Carousel slide</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="styles/b/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel ="stylesheet" href= "css/main.css">
<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media   queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">   </script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">  </script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>


 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
   <img src="img/mountain.jpg" alt="Mountain">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Mountain</h3>
    <p>Lovely picture of a mountain.</p>
   </div>
  </div>

 <div class="item">
  <img src="img/sunset.jpg" alt="sunset">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Sunset</h3>
    <p>The atmosphere in Chania has a touch of Florence and Venice.</p>
   </div>
  </div>


 <!-- Left and right controls -->
 <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"   data-slide="prev">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
 </a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button"      data-slide="next">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
 </a>
</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3 /jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
This is the image outcome I receive. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Can someone help out please. I also need to :

- have the background span the entire page, while the content still stays in the center area.
- make the arrows to scroll small and over the image?
- auto scroll it

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147500037 source: file:///C:/Users/Kosio/Desktop/Web%20Projects/Carousel%20Slider%20Boot%20Kishav/styles/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2

Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:11:126805
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.

Answer (score 1):

First: You have a `</div>` missing below your second `.item` div.
Oh, I forgot: you have a space in your jQuery url before */jquery.min.js*, that should be removed.

To achieve making the image centered and height always the same (first point):

```
#myCarousel {
    height: 256px;
}

#myCarousel img {
    max-height: 256px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.carousel-inner {
    text-align: center;
}
```

It scrolls automatically by default, to change interval add `data-interval="<yourspeed>"` either to your `.carousel` div fpr all images or to every `.item` div to get different intervals for each image. That was your third point.

Second I don't understand.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/suex/gra6t7t0/)

Comment: My main problem is that the website is still displayed as I've shown on the image above. I can't find a way to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. It was with the correct placement of the fonts file. Also thanks for the help with the CSS!